# Ссылку из Chrome или Firefox открыть в IE

Tags: webbrowser, браузер

Имеется некая ссылка, которая ведет на ресурс, который работает только в IE. Возможно ли чтобы ресурс открывался в IE при клике на ссылку из других браузеров, например из Chrome или Firefox, и если да то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://адрес сайта">Открыть сайт</a>
```

Не знаю только, насколько данная фича мультибраузерная и мультиплатформенная. И в целом больше смахивает на костыль, чем на оптимальное решение.

Comment: Костыль, согласен( Но в IE корректно работает флеш, а в гугле и лисичке виснет((( а политика предприятия не позволяет обновить браузеры до версии в которой флеш не виснит (например до chroma v67)...

Comment: Ну и нужно понимать, что подобное будет работать только если сам IE установлен. Если в рамках предприятия, то, вероятно, это единственный выход и наименее болезненный, учитывая особенности задачи.